# Firing event on new tab of browser in LeanFt using C#

Tags: automated-testing, browser-automation, agile-testing, qtp

In my application flow, a new tab is opened in Google Chrome after clicking a button, I want to fire more click events and test the application in this new tab but the click events are not getting fired.

Below is what I have tried so far:

```
IBrowser myNewTab = BrowserFactory.Attach(new BrowserDescription
{
    Title = "MyNewTabTitle"
});

IWebElement newTabObject = myNewTab.Describe<IWebElement>(new WebElementDescription
 {
     XPath = "XPath_Of_My_Control_On_New_Tab"
 });
newTabObject.Click();
```

But after executing this I am still getting the error as, threw exception:

```
HP.LFT.SDK.ReplayObjectNotFoundException: attachApplication
```

I have also tried to apply different properties for `newTabObject` like `Title`, `Url`.

Comment: After clicking on it are you directly navigating to the newly opened tab?

Answer (score 1):

You need to switch to the new tab which is a new window.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588827/how-to-switch-to-the-new-browser-window-which-opens-after-click-on-the-button